# Object possibly null even with default parameter value

Tags: typescript

I have this simple function, that takes a string and returns it in title case:

```
const toTitleCase = (str: string = 'test'): string => {
  const regex = /^[a-z]{0,1}|\s\w/gi;

  str = str.toLowerCase();

  str!.match(regex).forEach((char) => {
    str = str.replace(char, char.toUpperCase());
  });

  return str;
};
```

Even with the `!` in `str!.match` as well as the default value for the parameter I get an "Object is possibly null" error from the TSC on that line. What gives?

Comment: if the match fails then `str.match()` returns null and calling `.forEach` on that is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

the part that is possibly null is `str.match(regex)` since if the regex doesn't find any matches it returns null instead of an empty list, so you would probably want to do this:

```
(str.match(regex) ?? []).forEach(...)
```

This indicates that if the match is `undefined` or `null` then use an empty list, although your regex is setup well to always match the beginning of a line so you would be safe to instead just use an assertion:

```
str.match(regex)!.forEach(...)
```